# Extend dictionary to include word frequencies

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary that I am building up for NLTK sentiment analysis.

Note: the input is plain text email content.

```
def word_feats(words):
    stopset = list(set(stopwords.words('english')))

    words_split = words.split()

    result = dict([(word, True) for word in words_split if word not in stopset])

    return result
```

I would like to extend this to include word frequencies in the dictionary along with the unique words.

This is what I currently get:

```
'To' (4666843744) = {bool} True
'ensure' (4636385096) = {bool} True
'email' (4636383752) = {bool} True
'updates' (4636381960) = {bool} True
'delivered' (4667509936) = {bool} True
'inbox,' (4659135800) = {bool} True
'please' (4659137368) = {bool} True
'add' (4659135016) = {bool} True
```

I'd like something like the following where the numbers on the end are the frequencies. It doesn't have to be exactly like this but I'd like to be able to access the frequencies for each word.

```
'To' (4666843744) = {bool} True, 100
'ensure' (4636385096) = {bool} True, 3
'email' (4636383752) = {bool} True, 40
'updates' (4636381960) = {bool} True, 3
'delivered' (4667509936) = {bool} True, 4
'inbox,' (4659135800) = {bool} True, 20
'please' (4659137368) = {bool} True, 150
'add' (4659135016) = {bool} True, 10
```

Comment: Please provide your `input` and required `output`

Comment: @KaushikNP thank you for helping me to improve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) should do the trick:

```
from collections import Counter
result = dict(Counter(word for word in words_split if word not in stopset))
```

Comment: Close but now I am missing the True boolean part. I think this might be required by NLTK

Comment: Note that any non-zero integer will evaluate to True in Python so this should work.

Comment: I'll try it now